# amazon-ssm-agent failing to restart after reboot on Windows Server 2019 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-systems-manager

We are applying patches to our Windows instances using the patch manager function in AWS Systems Manager. We have a patch baseline that is executed against a set of windows instances (each of which are part of a patch group) by executing a maintenance window which in turn executes a run command against each of the instances. However we are finding the following:

1. The instances in question seem to get patches installed correctly. Executing `wmic qfe list` shows that the patches have been installed on the target machines
2. The target instances are then rebooted after patches are installed
3. The run command remains in progress indefinitely

From more investigation we found that the amazon-ssh-agent failed to start when the instances are rebooted. The error logs were as follows:

```
[devInstanceA]: PS C:\ProgramData\Amazon\SSM\Logs> get-content .\errors.log -tail 20           
2020-11-09 09:36:02 ERROR [func1 @ coremanager.go.246] [instanceID=i-04b3ce4e6e53b0b6f] error occurred trying to start core module. Plugin name: StartupProcessor. Error: Internal error occurred by startup processor: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Once we manually restarted the amazon-ssh-agent again the run command completed successfully. This issue is we dont want to have to manually start the amazon-ssh-agenton each instance especially as we have alot of instances!

Any ideas on what is causing this, i.e. why is the amazon-ssh-agent not starting up successfully after automatic reboot?